# Чтение тегов MP3 без использования сторонних библиотек

Tags: c#, mp3

Я видел много статей о том как читать теги mp3 с помощью разных библиотек. Есть ли способ сделать это без их использования? Если можете, поделитесь кодом пожалуйста.

Comment: Есть: читаете MP3, затем парсите его, то есть реализовываете у себя те самые разные библиотеки.

Comment: Изучить формат/структуру файла-MP3 и написать собственные функции доступа. Которые, скорее всего, просто явят собой новую библиотеку :)

Comment: Может первая же ссылка из гугла по запросу [формат mp3 файла](http://habrahabr.ru/post/103635/) поможет?

Comment: [ID3 tag version 2.4.0 - Main Structure](http://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-structure), [ID3 tag version 2.4.0 - Native Frames](http://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-frames) - впринципе там ничего сложного. Но проще всё-таки не городить велосипед

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В библиотеке .NET нет стандартных классов для работы с тегами ID3. Для того, чтобы сделать, что Вы хотите, Вам нужно самим реализовать спецификацию ID3V2 - там 2 документа: ["Main Structure"](http://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-structure) и ["Native Frames"](http://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-frames). В принципе, ничего сложного там нет, но очень много и нудно, поэтому чтобы не городить велосипедов проще взять что-то готовое - например библиотеку [taglib-sharp](https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp).

Если же Вы всё-таки хотите поковыряться в этом сами, а переводить официальную спецификацию не хочется или сложно, то я в свое время переводил её для себя ([ID3v2.4.0-russian-translate](https://github.com/elp87/ID3v2.4.0-russian-translate/releases/tag/1.0)). Правда повторюсь, переводил для себя, этот перевод нельзя использовать как официальный и абсолютно достоверный.

---

Помимо тега id3v2 в файле mp3 может храниться тег id3v1. Он ущербен, устарел и имеет ряд ограничений, но в некоторых случаях может быть полезен и реализует в 10 строк.
Ограничения тега id3v1:

1. На поля отводится фиксированное, малое количество символов
2. Кодировка только в ISO 8859-1
3. Малое количество полей

Черновая реализация:

```
public class Id3v1
{
    private const string TAGID = "TAG";

    private byte[] tagid = new byte[3];
    private byte[] title = new byte[30];
    private byte[] artist = new byte[30];
    private byte[] album = new byte[30];
    private byte[] year = new byte[4];
    private byte[] comment = new byte[28];
    private byte[] genre = new byte[1];
    private byte[] bitrate = new byte[1];
    private byte[] duration = new byte[1];

    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return Encoding.Default.GetString(title).TrimEnd('\0');
        }            
    }

    public string Artist
    {
        get
        {
            return Encoding.Default.GetString(artist).TrimEnd('\0');
        }
    }

    public string Album
    {
        get
        {
            return Encoding.Default.GetString(album).TrimEnd('\0');
        }
    }

    public string Year
    {
        get
        {
            return Encoding.Default.GetString(year).TrimEnd('\0');
        }
    }

    public string Comment
    {
        get
        {
            return Encoding.Default.GetString(comment).TrimEnd('\0');
        }
    }

    public byte Genre
    {
        get
        {
            return genre[0];
        }
    }

    public string Bitrate
    {
        get
        {
            return Encoding.Default.GetString(bitrate).TrimEnd('\0');
        }
    }

    public string Duration
    {
        get
        {
            return Encoding.Default.GetString(duration).TrimEnd('\0');
        }
    }

    public Id3v1(string filename)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
        {
            fs.Seek(-128, SeekOrigin.End);
            fs.Read(tagid, 0, tagid.Length);

            //Проверка наличие тега по заголовку "TAG" в начале
            if (Encoding.Default.GetString(tagid) == TAGID)
            {
                fs.Read(title, 0, title.Length);
                fs.Read(artist, 0, artist.Length);
                fs.Read(album, 0, album.Length);
                fs.Read(year, 0, year.Length);
                fs.Read(bitrate, 0, bitrate.Length);
                fs.Read(duration, 0, duration.Length);
                fs.Read(comment, 0, comment.Length);
                fs.Read(genre, 0, genre.Length);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NoId3v1Exception();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Пример использования:

```
public void ArtistTest()
{
    string expArtist = "Sting";

    Id3v1 id3 = new Id3v1("test.mp3");

    Assert.AreEqual(expArtist, id3.Artist);
}
```