# Отобразить сведения о файле в Label

Tags: c#, winforms

Добавляю в ListBox аудио файлы. Нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на Button в Label отображалась информация о выбранном в ListBox файле. Например скорость потока кбит в сек.

Comment: И в чём собственно вопрос?.. Или Вы хотите чтобы задачу за Вас решили "с нуля"?.. Конкретизируйте пожалуйста вопрос, опишите подробнее, что Вы сделали и с чем у Вас возникла проблема.

Comment: В вопросе нет просьбы решить с нуля. Хочу узнать как делать и с чего начинать.

Comment: Список Вы построили. У Вас проблема с обработкой события клика? получением выбранного элемента списка? получением информации о файле? отображением данной информации в Label?

Comment: Посмотрите этот вопрос [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/442211/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2-mp3-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA)

Comment: Для получения битрейта и тому подобной информации, нужна какая-нибудь библиотека для работы с медиа-файлами. Например, TagLib.

Answer (score 0):

У тебя должен где-то в программе храниться путь к этим файлам.

Просто, создаешь объект FileInfo и передаешь ему путь к файлу и считываешь свойство Length